# how to get the data from a configfile

Tags: python, nose

I am writing a test for a function where i am trying to get the data from configrc file. but somehow it's not happening.

```
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    with open(".configrc", "r") as file: 
        data = config.read(file)         
    mode_in_rc = data    
    assert mode_in_rc == mode
```

Comment: please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

I like the approach of using a class for this very much:

configfile.py:

```
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class config():
    DIR = basedir
    ANOTHER_KEY = "thisisasetting"
    DEBUG = False
```

using the settings in any other file:

```
from configfile import config

print(config.ANOTHER_KEY)
print(f"""running in {}""", config.DIR)
```

This way it is easy to drag them along.